# Do I really need to use openstack?

Tags: virtualization, cloud, openstack

There is a lot of hype on the Ubuntu website at the moment about openstack and I am planning to setup a few virtualised servers on Ubuntu anyway. My question is that I'm not sure if openstack would benefit me. What does it actually do/help out with. I just can't seem to get my head around it as there are too many "the cloud" buzzwords in the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to work on many things to make a cloud work. If you just need a few VMs, do not use it.

You can read more from here:

https://superuser.com/questions/318103/what-is-openstack-and-how-can-it-be-used

But if you want to learn / know what is cloud, spend one or two weeks with it.